# 404.js vs _error.js warning

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling

- warn Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload

[image]

How do we get rid of this warning? I tried everything

Answer (score 1):

the link you provided itself, giving information:

**Why This Error Occurred**

Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload when you edited a file. It may be because:

- The file you're editing might have other exports in addition to a React component.
- Your React component is an anonymous function.
- The component name is in `camelCase` and not `PascalCase`, for example, `textField` instead of `TextField`.

you can check by yourself here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload